# How to setup an unprotected Ad Hoc (IBSS) Network and if possible with WPA encryption?

Tags: wifi, raspbian-stretch, systemd

There are several tutorials out there to setup an Ad Hoc network, for example [Ad Hoc setup in RPi 3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/49792/79866). But how can I do this using **systemd-networkd**? And all what I've found is using unprotected communication without encryption. Is it possible to use a setup with WPA encryption?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are mainly three setups to have a peer to peer network:

- unprotected ad-hoc interface by configuring the WiFi device
- unprotected ad-hoc interface using wpa_supplicant (Recommended)
- **Only with suitable (RSN-IBSS capable) USB dongle**:
  protected ad-hoc interface using wpa_supplicant and WPA encryption (best solution if possible)
- ad-hoc interface with additional USB/WiFi dongle for uplink to internet router

Tested with
[Raspberry Pi OS with desktop 2020-08-20 based on Buster](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_armhf/images/raspios_armhf-2020-08-24/) updated on 2020-11-21.
For older versions look at [Revision 11](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/revisions/94048/11)
Updates done with `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade && sudo reboot`.

---

### ♦ Setup systemd-networkd

Just follow to [Use systemd-networkd for general networking](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108593/79866). You can use section **"♦ Quick Step"**. Then come back here.

Configure interface **wlan0**:

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es   # if not already done
rpi ~# rfkill unblock wlan
rpi ~# systemctl disable --now wpa_supplicant.service
```

Create this file:

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wl*
[Network]
MulticastDNS=yes
LinkLocalAddressing=yes
EOF
```

---

### ♦ Setup unprotected ad-hoc interface by configuring WiFi device

First follow section **♦ Setup systemd-networkd**.

To configure the wifi into ad-hoc mode we only have to execute two commands (don't do that now):

```
iw wlan0 set type ibss
iw wlan0 ibss join IBSS-RPiNet 2412 # frequency 2412 is channel 1
```

For a mapping of frequencies to channels look at [<sup>**3**</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels). I use a systemd unit so we can also stop the service. Create a new unit file with:

```
rpi ~# systemctl --force --full edit ad-hoc-interface@.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Unprotected ad-hoc (IBSS) interface
Requires=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
Before=network.target

[Service]
Environment="SSID=IBSS-RPiNet" "FREQUENCY=2412"
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStartPre=/sbin/iw %I set type ibss
ExecStart=/sbin/iw %I ibss join $SSID $FREQUENCY
ExecStopPost=-/sbin/iw dev %I ibss leave
ExecStopPost=-/sbin/iw %I set type managed

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

Enable the service:

```
rpi ~# systemctl enable ad-hoc-interface@wlan0.service
```

reboot.

Check with:

```
rpi ~$ iw dev
rpi ~$ iw dev wlan0 link
rpi ~$ ip addr
rpi ~$ sudo iw dev wlan0 scan | grep -B8 -A3 "SSID: IBSS-RPiNet"

# From another ad hoc connected device you should be able to
rpi ~$ ping -c3 raspberrypi.local


rpi ~$
```

You should be able to:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl stop ad-hoc-interface@wlan0.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl start ad-hoc-interface@wlan0.service
```

To change the *ssid* and *frequency* you can edit the unit file:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --full edit ad-hoc-interface@wlan0.service
```

---

### ♦ Setup unprotected ad-hoc interface using wpa_supplicant (Recommended)

If you start from a fresh flashed Raspbian image then first follow section **♦ Setup systemd-networkd**.

If you have tried *unprotected ad-hoc interface by configuring the WiFi device* then do `sudo systemctl disable --now ad-hoc-interface@wlan0.service`.

Wpa_supplicant has peer-to-peer enabled by default that is used by WiFi-Direct. This occupies the **wlan0** interface so you cannot enable IBSS mode. You will get the error messages:

```
Nov 21 22:06:17 wpa_supplicant[262]: nl80211: Failed to set interface into IBSS mode
Nov 21 22:06:17 wpa_supplicant[262]: wlan0: Association request to the driver failed
```

It is important to disable p2p with option `p2p_disabled=1`. Setup **wpa_supplicant** with this file and your settings (ssid, country, maybe frequency) and enable it:

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es   # if not already done
rpi ~# cat > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf <<EOF
ctrl_interface=DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
p2p_disabled=1
country=DE

network={
    ssid="IBSS-RPiNet"
    frequency=2412   # channel 1
    mode=1           # IBSS (ad-hoc, peer-to-peer)
    key_mgmt=NONE
}
EOF

rpi ~# chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
rpi ~# systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

reboot.

Check with:

```
rpi ~$ iw dev
rpi ~$ iw dev wlan0 link
rpi ~$ ip addr
rpi ~$ sudo iw dev wlan0 scan | grep -B8 -A3 "IBSS-RPiNet"

# From another ad hoc connected device you should be able to
rpi ~$ ping -c3 raspberrypi.local
```

---

### ♦ Setup protected RSN (WPA) ad-hoc interface using wpa_supplicant (best solution if possible)

First of all it must be said that **Raspberry Pi does not support encrypted IBSS connections!**. You have to use an additional USB WiFi dongle that usually registers an interface **wlan1**. My setup shows:

```
rpi ~$ iw list | grep -P "Wiphy|RSN-IBSS"
Wiphy phy1
        Device supports RSN-IBSS.
Wiphy phy0
```

You cannot find this support entry for `Wiphy pyh0` that is the on-board WiFi device.

So plug in your compatible WiFi dongle and if you start from a fresh flashed Raspbian image then first follow section **♦ Setup systemd-networkd**.

If you have tried *unprotected ad-hoc interface by configuring the WiFi device* then do `sudo systemctl disable --now ad-hoc-interface@wlan0.service`.

If you have tried *unprotected ad-hoc interface using wpa_supplicant* then do `sudo systemctl disable --now wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service`.

Then Setup **wpa_supplicant** with this file and your settings (country, ssid, psk and frequency) and enable it:

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es   # if not already done
rpi ~# cat > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf <<EOF
ctrl_interface=DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
p2p_disabled=1
country=DE

network={
    ssid="IBSS-RPiNet"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    proto=RSN
    psk="verySecretPassword"
    mode=1
    frequency=2412
}
EOF

rpi ~# chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf
rpi ~# systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan1.service
```

reboot.

Check with:

```
rpi ~$ iw dev
rpi ~$ iw dev wlan1 link
rpi ~$ ip addr
rpi ~$ sudo iw dev wlan1 scan | grep -B8 -A3 "IBSS-RPiNet"

# From another ad hoc connected device you should be able to
rpi ~$ ping -c3 raspberrypi.local
```

---

### ♦ Installing additional nodes

On additional nodes setup ad-hoc mode just the same way you have done with the first one as shown above.

---

### ♦ Setup ad-hoc interface with additional USB/WiFi dongle for uplink to internet router

If you want an uplink connection to an internet router you need an additional USB/WiFi dongle. I will use the onboard WiFi device for the uplink, so you are free to use the dongle as protected RSN interface if possible.

First follow section **♦ Setup systemd-networkd** if not already done. Then create these files with your settings (country, ssid, psk):

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es   # if not already done
rpi ~# cat > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf <<EOF
ctrl_interface=DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
p2p_disabled=1
country=DE

network={
    ssid="TestNet"
    psk="verySecretPassword"
}
EOF

rpi ~# chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
rpi ~# systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service

rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan0
[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
EOF
```

and for **wlan1**:

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf <<EOF
ctrl_interface=DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
p2p_disabled=1
country=DE

network={
    ssid="IBSS-RPiNet"
    frequency=2412   # channel 1
    mode=1           # IBSS (ad-hoc, peer-to-peer)
    key_mgmt=NONE
}
EOF

rpi ~# chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf
rpi ~# systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan1.service

rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/12-wlan1.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan1
[Network]
MulticastDNS=yes
LinkLocalAddressing=yes
EOF
```

reboot.

```
# you should be able to
rpi ~$ ping google.com

# From another ad hoc connected device you should be able to
rpi ~$ ping -c3 raspberrypi.local
```

---

### ♦ For developers and for troubleshooting

This are some things I have done to find the answer. I do not want to discard them because it has taken some effort and it may help me later and others on similar issues.

**manual setup**
For testing how it works you can execute these commands [2]. Be sure the interface isn't occupied by another service:

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
rpi ~# iw wlan0 set type ibss
rpi ~# ip link set wlan0 up
rpi ~# iw wlan0 ibss join RPiNet 2432
rpi ~# ip addr add 192.168.1.2/24 dev wlan0
rpi ~# ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2
rpi ~# exit

rpi ~$ # check with:
rpi ~$ iw dev
rpi ~$ iw dev wlan0 link
rpi ~$ ip addr
rpi ~$ sudo iw dev wlan0 scan | grep -B8 -A3 "SSID: RPiNet"
```

You can do this also on a second raspi with another ip address, e.g. 192.168.1.3. Then you can ping it.

**refefences:**
[1] [Howto migrate from networking to systemd-networkd with dynamic failover](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/78788/79866)
[2] [Ad-hoc networking](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ad-hoc_networking)
[3] [List of WLAN channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels)
[4] [Raspberry Pi 2018-04-18 - Cannot put device into adhoc mode](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/990)
[5] [Kernel trace in brcmfmac wifi driver when joining ad-hoc network w/another brcmfmac device](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1742)
[6] [Linux WiFi Ad-hoc mode](https://wiki.lm-technologies.com/linux-wifi-ad-hoc-mode/)
[7] [What is the difference between Ad-Hoc and Mesh Network? (also with p2p)](https://superuser.com/a/481367/879258)
[8] [Why Wi-Fi Direct can not replace Ad-hoc mode](http://www.thinktube.com/tech/android/wifi-direct)