# USB WiFi dongle ad-hoc criteria

Tags: networking, wifi, usb, raspbian-buster

I'm trying to setup an ad-hoc network (intranet-only, no internet) of RPi4s (Buster 2019-09-26) using dongles with detachable antennas. I can successfully

- setup ad-hoc modes on the internal WiFi (both 2GHz and 5GHz) and add `babeld` on top of it.
- get internet from a WiFi USB dongle (used `MrEngman` scripts to install drivers).

But I can't get ad-hoc to work on the dongles though - I set things up same as for `wlan0` but packets don't go through. Searching around indicates it's probably the dongle that can't do ad-hoc.

**My question is**: *what is the attribute I should look for in a dongle?* So far all were using the `rtl8822bu`, is that the culprit? How can I check ahead of time if a chipset will work? I don't mind scouring the internet looking for the right dongle, but I'm not sure what makes the right one right or why.

Current setup process in case it's not a hardware issue:

### `wlan0`

Setup `interfaces`

```
sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd.service
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Make it look like

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address xxx.xxx.xx.xx
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wireless-channel 44
    wireless-essid my_net
    wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

Then reboot

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo reboot
```

Do this for each Pi, changing the static IP, and you have an ad-hoc network!

### `wlan1`

Connect to the internet using `wlan0`, plug dongle in, then run

```
sudo wget http://www.fars-robotics.net/install-wifi -O /usr/bin/install-wifi
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/install-wifi
sudo install-wifi
```

You can now connect to the internet through your dongle! Now follow the `wlan0` steps but set it up for `wlan1` (and add `iface wlan0 inet dhcp` to the `interfaces` file).

---

### EDIT

Output from `sudo iw list | grep -A 12 -i "valid interface combinations"`

```
    Supported interface modes
        * IBSS
        * managed
        * AP
        * P2P-client
        * P2P-GO
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x1963
            RX LDPC
            HT20/HT40
            Static SM Power Save
            RX HT20 GI
            RX HT40 SGI
--
    Supported interface modes
        * IBSS
        * managed
        * AP
        * P2P-client
        * P2P-GO
        * P2P-device
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x1022
            HT20/HT40
            Static SM Power Save
            RX HT20 GI
            No RX STBC
```

Comment: Try `sudo iw list | grep -A 12 -i "supported interface modes"`

Comment: @Milliways not sure how to read this output...throwing it in the question edit. I'll note that quickly scanning through without the `grep` showed 2 bands, not sure if that matters.

Comment: What's "MrEngman scripts"?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev It's just the `install-wifi` scripts shown with that `wget`, they're posted in several places. They find the right drivers for the kernel version.

Comment: Noticed this question getting some views so I'll add this here: I managed to successfully build a mesh network using dongles with `babeld`...in 2.4GHz. I gave up on 5GHz mode. Not sure if that saves somebody a headache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every device that conform to IEEE 802.11 must support a wireless ad hoc network. In the specification it is called [independent basic service set (**IBSS**)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_(802.11_network)#Ad_hoc). The supported interface modes of your WiFi USB dongle show that it also supports it of course.

So **IBSS** is the keyword you have to look for your ad hoc network.

You are using old style deprecated Debian ifupdown managed in `/etc/network/interfaces` that somehow have to coexist with default **dhcpcd**. This may work with standard well known managed WiFi networks but I haven't found a working IBSS configuration with it. I have looked at IBSS with the straight forward **systemd-networkd** network management. Maybe you may find some ideas at [How to setup an unprotected Ad Hoc (IBSS) Network and if possible with WPA encryption?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/94048/79866). At section **♦ For developers and for troubleshooting** you will also find a manual setup for testing how it works.

Comment: I'll definitely look into the `nl` driver in that answer. The interfaces solution is really simple that's why I used it. If I can't isolate a driver issue I'll try `systemd` method.

Comment: Is there a way to stop `wpa_supplicant` altogether so it doesn't even have a chance to cause a driver issue? Similar to stopping the `dhcpcd` service?

Comment: Just to confirm, the first 2 bullets in the linked question `systemd` and `configuring WiFi device` should work regardless of the `nl` driver issue right? That should only be a problem if I do the `wpa_supplicant` method? Sorry, trying to make sense of all this!

Comment: @AntoineZambelli To persistent disable wpa_supplicant just execute `sudo systemctl disable --now wpa_supplicant.service`. I can confirm your assumption. The first bullet is only about disabling `ifupdown` and `dhcpcd` and enabling `systemd-networkd` and has nothing to do with ad-hoc networking. The second bullet configures the on-board WiFi device only by its driver an do not use wpa_supplicant so you do not have any problems with the background driver **nl80211** of it. It would be better to ask such things beneath the original linked answer.

Comment: I was able to get an ad-hoc network up on the `wlan0` interface (built-in WiFi). It works fine, but when I try to setup the same thing with `wlan1` (on the dongle) it doesn't work. All the `iw` checks come back the same, it shows connected to the network, but I can't ping the other Pi. Any changes to make to the "second bullet" method for `wlan1`?

Comment: @AntoineZambelli I don't know what you have done so I can't say much. If it is this old ifupdown stuff, I haven't used it since years. And I don't know what this `http://www.fars-robotics.net/install-wifi` is doing on **wlan1**. Have you tried to test it manual as described in section **♦ For developers and for troubleshooting - manual setup** in the setup I have linked? Does it work on **wlan1**?

Comment: `install-wifi` should just be installing the drivers for the chipset on the dongle (ie, `rtl8822bu`) - I guess I could build driver from source if all else fails. I'll try the manual setup first and update with any interesting logs/errors. And thanks for the help!

Comment: That driver installer script started spitting out 404s and I got bogged down in building from source and booting to the correct kernel headers. Anyways, your answer gets the right config and the linked question is really in-depth. Thanks for the help!