# Turning off and on ad hoc mode on raspberry pi

Tags: wifi, raspbian-stretch

I setup an ad hoc network between my computer and a pi for a project which works perfectly but when I have the ad-hoc on I have no access to the internet on the pi. There are times I am going to need internet to download code so I will have to switch it off so that I can connect to Wi-Fi. I could write a python script to manually edit the interfaces file each time I want to toggle it but I'm thinking there is a better way. Does anyone know a command of some type I can use to toggle on and off ad-hoc when I want?

Comment: I think, giving the ad hoc network internet access is a better solution. What ad hoc connection do you use? Do you use IBSS interface mode?

Comment: @Ingo I didn't think it would be possible to do that since it is a private network between two computers but I am very new to this. Yes I used IBSS mode I had to configure that on the laptop side of things. How would I give the Pi internet when I turn on the ad-hoc? Just as a reference I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BkfztZ0pOE&t=353s) tutorial.

Comment: For permanent internet connection you need a second interface, eth0 or wlan1 with an additional USB/WiFi dongle. Then the RasPi can also provide internet for all other connected ad hoc devices. For switch mode you can simply use systemd-networkd. Are you able to connect the RasPi with an ethernet cable to the internet router or do you can have a USB/WiFi dongle available? Do you really need oldstable Raspbian Stretch? I wouldn't use it anymore.

Comment: @Ingo Yes I do have a USB WIFI dongle and an Ethernet cable. I would prefer a solution which uses the dongle due to the nature of my project as a drone. I don't have a particular reason for using Raspbian Stretch it's just what I am used to and what I have done all my work on. What would you recommend? What I am gathering from you is that it is possible to have the Pi output a network on wlan0 while also receiving a WIFI connection on a wlan1 over the dongle if I set it up right. I would need to research that. Also, what do you mean by "systemd-networkd"

Comment: I will test a solution with IBSS ad hoc connections and with an additional dongle for internet access, using systemd-networkd with up to date Raspberry Pi OS based on Buster. Just a moment please, then I will write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a comment You also agree with a permanent uplink connection to an internet router. For this you can use the unused **eth0** interface or an additional USB/WiFi dongle. With the latter you can use the onboard WiFi device for a protected uplink and the dongle for a RSN protected ad hoc connection if supported. You are always free to use an unprotected connection. Look at [How to setup an unprotected Ad Hoc (IBSS) Network and if possible with WPA encryption?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/94048/79866) and use section **♦ Setup ad-hoc interface with additional USB/WiFi dongle for uplink to internet router**.