# Raspbian ad hoc networking issue with wlan0 set to type ibss

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, wifi-direct

I am following the instruction given by [How to setup an unprotected Ad Hoc (IBSS) Network and if possible with WPA encryption?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94047/how-to-setup-an-unprotected-ad-hoc-ibss-network-and-if-possible-with-wpa-encry/94048#94048) but the probelm occurs when I get to the line
`iw wlan0 set type ibss`
An error happens:
command failed: Device or resource busy
I Am using Raspbian buster latest version.

Comment: Did you exec sudo ifconfig wlan0 down before?

Comment: Yes, I found the solution. I post it

Answer (score 1):

The latest raspbian uses wpa_suppplicant, this needs to be disabled in order to change the wlan0 type. Run this command:
`killall wpa_supplicant`

Comment: Have you also tried just executing sudo ifconfig wlan0 down, then your cmd and then sudo ifconfig wlan0 up. This should also work.

Comment: Yes, first tried that.

Comment: Another thing to note is that apparently you can't add a virtual interface to pi (I'm using Zero 2) without sharing the channel. If you don't want to share channel you can just make the wlan0 interface itself as IBSS as in the link posted by OP

https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=138730